# Load cassandra schema programmatically

Tags: linux, nosql, cassandra

I'm trying to install and configure cassandra programmatically using a shell script.
I install cassandra, run `./cassandra` and then I try to load the schema using `cassandra-cli --host localhost -f <schema-file>`. The problem is that it tries to load the schema before cassandra is up and throws an exception. Is there any way to know when cassandra is up and running?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check to see if anything is listening on 9160 (the Thrift port) prior to loading the schema.  Binding to the port is the last thing the service does, and indicates it's ready to service requests.

If Cassandra is running this command will return something:

```
sudo lsof -i :9160
```

Answer (score 0):

use `./cassandra -f` then you will know it when Cassandra starts to listen on the Thrift port

Comment: I tried your solution, but when the script is running it hangs waiting to take control to continue executing. THX for answering!

Comment: would you plz be more specific? Hang in where? It goes well when it prints "start to listen on thrift port" or something.